# Apache Mod_Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm struggling writing a .htaccess file to basically map the following domains:

- `dev.domain.com/$1 => index.php/dev/$1`
- `api.domain.com/$1 => index.php/api/$1`
- `domain.com/$1 => index.php/front/$1`
- `www.domain.com/$1 => index.php/front/$1`

At the moment, everything is mapping to `index.php/$1` with the following configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is what came with the php framework I'm using by default. Any help would be greatly appreciated :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to map the requested paths based on the domain name, then you can use an additional `RewriteCond` and match the `HTTP_HOST` first.

You will have to multiply your block of existing RewriteConds and the RewriteRule for each domain - except for the last pair which could just be a default:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/dev/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/api/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/front/$1 [L]
```

Not tested. But see also the article on serverfault [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask), which explains the interactions between conditions and rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks! How would I allow the `domain\.com` to be anything? It would be great if this could run in both a production and development environment on different domains :)

Comment: @tarnfeld: To allow everything you can just leave out the condition for one rule block. Like in the last example. (Or match against `.*` for symmetry.)