# Wildcard apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, wildcard

I'm trying to write a mod_rewrite to work like this

- `domain.com` => `index.php`
- `anything.anotherdomain.com` => `index.php/anything`
- `foo.blabla.com` => `index.php/foo`
- `wildcard.maybeanother.com/bar/bla` => `index.php/wildcard/bar/bla`

Here is the config I have, but apache just throws a 500 error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^*\.*
    RewriteRule ^(*\.*)$ index.php/$1/$2 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Has anybody got any idea whats wrong with this? :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is index.php a folder? It seems strange that you'd have index.php/something/something

Comment: well kind of, the answers to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127011/apache-mod-rewrite) works ok, but i didn't want to rely on the specific `dev.domain.com` or `api.domain.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^$ index.php/%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I was hoping for it not to be `domain.com` specific? Will add that to my question :)

Comment: Does it work? Also, I made a few more slight changes just to make the rules more specific.

Comment: Nope :( Also by looking at it I dont think it would do what I want. I want on the request `api.domain.com/path` to hit "api" to `index.php/api/path`, where `api` is actually the first bit on the domain - if that makes sense? :)

Comment: That's what the %1 is for. It gets the subdomain from the RewriteCond. Are you still getting a 500 error? It might be getting into an infinite redirect loop, but those are always tricky and I never know if that's the problem or not.

Comment: Theres no 500 anymore but only the root of the domain goes to the index.php file, and it doesnt take into account the `api` bit, and if you put anything on the end it shows a 404 - like `api.domain.com/something` but `domain.com/something` does work

Comment: Are you sure you have your subdomain configured to point to the same folder on the server as the primary domain?

Comment: Yep, because if I just visit `api.domain.com` it shows the same as `domain.com`

Comment: Okay, I think I have it working [almost perfectly]. See my edited answer. The only problem I'm having with it is that it will serve a 500 error instead of a 404 if the file at the path it's rewriting to doesn't exist. However, I don't think that will be a problem since your framework problem handles 404s, so see what happens.

Comment: It's still not matching :( Hmm, the domain i'm testing this on has 4 parts, api.domain.second.local - maybe this could be the cause?

Comment: That would be why. :p I updated the answer again. Give it another try.